# IOS Save Association Array With NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: ios, plist, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

I'd like to save an `NSObject` using `NSKeyedArchiver` and save its association `NSArray`.

A User has many skills (not more than 6 or 7). Skills are an `NSArray` of `NSObjects` with `NSCoding` protocol, in the User Model

```
//User.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *skills;
```

Are Users and Skills are to be saved separately in 2 different `.plist` files and skills retrieved with a userID? Or is the skills array included in the **initWithCoder** and **decodeWithCoder** methods?

Answer (score 1):

Objects that conform to the `NSCoding` protocol can be saved to (and read from) a file using the `NSKeyedArchiver` class.

**NSCoding**

Many common `Objective-C` classes already conform to `NSCoding`. You can save objects of any of these types without doing anything special:

> NSArray
>   NSData
>
> NSDate
>
> NSDictionary
>
> NSNumber
>
> NSString

If you aren't sure whether a class supports `NSCoding`, check its class documentation.

For custom classes, you must add the **encodeWithCoder**: and **initWithCoder**: methods to your class to conform to the `NSCoding` protocol.

[Here you can get what you are looking for](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/Saving_Data/NSKeyedArchiver.html)

Comment: Thank you, I understand that these types can be saved. My question was oriented : how do you save an array of NSObjects conforming to NSCoding inside a class that conforms to NSCoding? Are there 2 completely separate entities that you save independentely, or are they saved in a single call?

Comment: what do you mean by single call?

Comment: I mean by that, that the Skills Array is not part of encodeWithCoder: and initWithCoder: methods in the User model right? There is a Users.plist and a Skills.plist so the models should be save separately. Skills should be retrieved with a userID fields. No?